# MYOB ODBC ASP.NET application issues during insert command from IIS 10.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, odbc, iis-express, myob

I am trying to develop a ASP.NET Web API for MYOB that runs within IIS. That will allow me to insert/update/select different pieces of information from a MYOB company file.

At the moment within development everything works perfectly from within VS 2015 using IIS Express. I can successfully execute a insert command on the MYOB ODBC connection in multi-user access mode while the company file is opened by atleast two other users.

However when run from within IIS no errors are displayed. However the ODBC driver returns successfully on the insert query despite no insert being completed and no records of errors in any log files.

Finally, i have given the application pool connected to the IIS Application/Website the identity of the system administrator account. So i am assuming this is not the issue.

Could someone please help me on this! Have I maybe setup the permissions and security protocols in IIS incorrectly? As this application works fine within IIS Express but not in IIS?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You eventually couldn't see an error because you are using Web API. You are just a client. But maybe the API has an error that you've couldn't be seen. is your API has a LOGS? or it has a return value when it might encountered an error?

Try to Double Check it.

I agreed there's a big difference between iis express and IIS itself(Not in VS, means other machine or in server)

Check it too.

```
1.) framework you are working mostly.
2.) make sure that your Web API is running.
3.) IIS set up.
```

Comment: I am using .net 4.6 and i believe it is running in IIS sufficiently. As other functions of the WEB Api such as the GET method for reading customer data out of MYOB is fully functional. It just seems to be an issue where there MYOB ODBC insert/update function doesnt work when the MYOB file is opened else where. But this only happens when using IIS and not in IIS Express. Hmmm

Comment: i dont understand what MYOB is

Comment: Sorry, MYOB is an accounting package. Would you happen to know what permission difference would occur when moving from IIS Express to IIS even though i have given the IIS application pool identity admin? Thanks